# Core Data Migration: are always new SQLLite tables created again?

Tags: macos, core-data

I've made a small change to my database (just added a new entity to my model) and created a lightweight mapping model to handle the migration.

The migration still seems to be quite slow, looking at the log of the migration, it seems all SQL Lite tables are created again and all data migrated.

So, this is how Core Data works? I can't have a faster migration?

ps. I've a complex model, with 30 entities, and many relationships. They are not inheriting from the same parent entity. Maybe core data is not designed to handle such complexity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migration is a relatively rare event. It can take a while, especially for large, complex models with lots of data.

I am not entirely sure that new tables are created, but I think that this is indeed happening. It is how I would implement the migration if Core Data did not do it for me.

Here are some suggestions for improvement:

1. Make sure the migration occurs in the background. Inform your user and keep the app responsive as much as possible.
2. Perhaps something went wrong when you "created a lightweight mapping model". If you are doing not more than a certain subset of changes (see the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH4-SW1)), "Lightweight Migration" does **not** require you to create a mapping model.

Comment: I don't understand from the documentation if the automatic data migration, without a mapping model, generates new tables as with the mapping model based migration (for tables that didn't change, I mean)

Comment: The documentation does not explain this. For the purposes of the migration it is largely irrelevant.

Comment: But it is not irrelevant in terms of performances. If, as I believe, all tables are repopulated than even an almost unchanged model is gonna take a while to migrate.